# Can we write the likelihood of a GLM in generality?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, likelihood, link-function

So I know we can explicitly write down the likelihood of any specified GLM model, for example the likelihood for the logistic regression model would be

$$L(\mathbf{\beta};y,x)=\prod_{i=1}^np(x_i)^{y_i}(1-p(x_i))^{1-y_i}\,,$$
but now I would like to know is there a way (or a standard convention) for writing $L(\beta;y,x)$ in general for any GLM?

Could I write in generality something like this
$$L(\beta;y,x)=\prod_{i=1}^n[ N(y,x;\beta,\sigma^2)\times \eta(p)]$$
where $\eta(p)$ is the link function that relates $y$ and $p$?

At the end of the day, I would like to be able to write down my likelihood as the product of normals (the linear part) and incorporate the link function into it somehow.

Comment: No. The likelihood of a generic GLM is $$L(\mathbf{\beta};y,x)=\prod_{i=1}^np(x_i)^{y_i}(1-p(x_i))^{1-y_i}\,,$$where $p(x)$ depends on the type of link function you choose.

Comment: In the case above that is a specific GLM right?

Comment: I guess what I mean by that is if my data were counts (like a Poisson) then the above wouldn't be the likelihood so not generic.

Comment: Well, you could write the exponential family in a [general form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Probability_distribution) and then substitute in the [link function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function) with an some appropriate index for the observation to put it in the product, you'd have a generic form for the likelihood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic likelihood for a GLM is$$\prod_{i=1}^n f(y_i|\lambda(x_i))$$where the parameter $\lambda$ of the default distribution (Binomial, Poisson, Normal, &tc.) is related to the covariate vector $x$ by the link function $\lambda(x)$.